Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AuthController (?, LoginService, LogoutService)
I am trying to implement authentication with nest js. When I run the code I get an error like this:

Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AuthController (?, LoginService, LogoutService). Please make sure that the argument MeService at
index [0] is available in the AuthModule context.

AuthController file
@Controller('auth')
export class AuthController {
    constructor(
        private readonly meService: MeService,
        private readonly loginService: LoginService,
        private readonly logoutService: LogoutService
    ) {}

AuthModue
@Module({
    imports: [forwardRef(() => UsersModule)],
    providers: [MeService, LoginService, LogoutService],
    controllers: [AuthController]
})
export class AuthModule {}

UsersModule
@Module({
    imports: [RolesModule, TypeOrmModule.forFeature([User])],
    providers: [
        UserRepository,
        ShowService,
        IndexService,
        CreateService,
        UpdateService,
        DeleteService
    ],
    controllers: [UsersController],
    exports: [UserRepository]
})
export class UsersModule {}

MeService
@Injectable()
export class MeService {
    constructor(
        @Inject(forwardRef(() => UserRepository))
        private userRepository: UserRepository
    ) {}

    async handle(id: string): Promise<User> {
        if (!id) {
            throw new UnauthorizedException(en.unauthorized);
        }

        return this.userRepository.findOne({
            where: { id },
            relations: {
                createdBy: true,
                role: true
            },
            withDeleted: true
        });
    }
}


UserRepository
@Injectable()
export class UserRepository extends AbstractRepository<User> {
    constructor(
        @InjectRepository(User)
        protected readonly repository: Repository<User>
    ) {
        super();
    }

    async findByEmail(email: string, options: FindOneOptions<User> = {}) {
        const finalOptions = deepMerge(options, { where: { email } });

        return this.repository.findOne(finalOptions);
    }
}


AbstractRepository
@Injectable()
export abstract class AbstractRepository<T extends { id: string }> {
    protected abstract readonly repository: Repository<T>;

    findAll(options: FindManyOptions<T> = {}): Promise<T[]> {
        return this.repository.find(options);
    }
}

I tried to get rid of forwardRef func but i still get that error

You can remove the forwardRef and use the normal private read-only method, and make sure to export the meSerivce in the AuthModule

i got rid of the forwardRef and i still get that error, dont know why would i export the meService since its a part of the AuthModule and its not used enywhere else

@Inject(forwardRef(() => UserRepository)) remove this from me service

i removed it and it still doesn't work

can you provide the minium working repository via GitHub

I've made pr to this repository. can you please check that

did you test that code in your PR? i still get that error with your changes

Yes, it's working on my end. Can you create a separate branch in the main repository so I can make the pr to that branch

my initial intent was to import the services(MeService, LoginService) directly from AuthModule but your code works, thanks

I run the code, and work fine, but i have problem with imports. I use node v20. I just need to make imports again.
